# Apply HoldForm on only a part of an expression

Tags: evaluation, hold, printing

This expression:

```
Det[Array[a, {3, 3}]]
```

is evaluated as:

$-a(1,3) a(2,2) a(3,1)+a(1,2) a(2,3) a(3,1)+a(1,3) a(2,1) a(3,2)-a(1,1) a(2,3)a(3,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1) a(3,3)+a(1,1) a(2,2) a(3,3)$

If I `HoldForm` it:

```
HoldForm[Det[Array[a, {3, 3}]]
```

Neither `Det` or `Array` is evaluated:

$| \text{Array}[a,\{3,3\}]|$

However, is it possible to hold `Det` only, so that it prints:

$\text{Det}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
 a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
 a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

?

Comment: I think `Inactivate` would give you the fine grain control you seek. You can inactivate one head specifically, e.g. `Det`, while leaving everything else as it normally would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the solutions of Nasser and Syed you could inactivate the `Det` function like this:

```
array = Array[a, {3, 3}];

Inactive[Det][array]
```

[image]

If you want it in the matrix form, you can do it either like in the answer of Nasser, or like this:

```
MapAt[MatrixForm, Inactive[Det][array], {1}]
```

[image]

In the both cases, `Det` will be shown blended.

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

> However, is it possible to hold Det only, so that it prints:

$$
\text{Det}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
 a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
 a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I am not sure if you mean you want Latex output, or Mathematica output for display only.

If you mean Mathematica output for display use only, then you can take advantage that `MatrixForm` is a wrapper which prevents evaluation. So you can

```
ClearAll[a]
array = Array[a, {3, 3}]
Det[MatrixForm[array]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can *not* use  the above for computation, since `MatrixForm` is inside.

If you want later to use normal array, you can do

```
Det[array]
```

Comment: It should read: "You can NOT use the above for computation, since MatrixForm is inside."

Comment: @DanielHuber. Thanks. typo fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For display purposes only:

```
arr = Array[a, {3, 3}]
arrT = arr // TraditionalForm

RowBox[{"Det", arrT, "=", TraditionalForm@Det[arr]}] // DisplayForm
```

[image]